# iPhone: Can any application be accessed even when the phone is in locked mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

We are going to create a life saving app. This app is made for those critical and emergency conditions when someone fall ill suddenly.

As this application is for emergency case, we need to make this app accessible even when the phone is locked.

Is there any way including public or private API, we can implement the feature?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS isn't designed to be a life saver, it's designed to make income for Apple (to be crude, because many things you think would be possible just is not)

There is also the reason with battery life, memory usage etc that needs to be restricted in a mobile environment where power is not unlimited.

You could however look at things like Push Notifications (read the docs). The app won't be "accessible" in the sense, but you can have a chance users will launch the app when you ask them to - they will actively have to push a "ok open the app" button.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggestnlooking into gestures to perhaps overide the lock for your apps usage. Whether it gets approved by Apple is another story.